# Вопрос Try / Catch   Android

Tags: android, java

Почему, если я пишу:

```
type = json.getJSONObject(0).getString("type");
```

или

```
map.put("id_cat",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_cat"));
```

Всегда **красным** подчеркнут ***json.getJSONObject(i)*** и предлагает мне всегда сделать так:

```
try {                                   map.put("name",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name_cat"));                                   map.put("id_cat",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_cat"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

После добавления **Try/catch** , Все работает на Ура!, но только код ужасно большой из-за этих проверок. можно их отключить как-то ?

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы совсем не знаете Java. Это вопрос ученика-новичка первой недели.

Comment: К сожалению, разработчики некоторых библиотек настолько упороты, что явно злоупотребляют `checked exceptions`, даже там, где, казалось бы, очевидно использование как раз `unchecked`. `org.json` — яркий пример таких вот умельцев, работая с поделием которых хочется плеваться и громко нецензурно выражаться. Как вариант решения сложившейся ситуации — перейти на `gson`/`jackson`/etc.

Comment: Интересно, кстати, а за что вопрос минусуют?

Comment: @falstaf Потому что вопрос не представляет из себя никакой ценности и ответом на него должно быть RTFM! Было бы неплохо добавить такую причину для закрытия вопроса.

Comment: @a_gura, если так рассуждать, то и ХэшКод/SO-подобные ресурсы не существовали бы, поскольку 99% вопросов, задаваемых там, решаются пресловутым RTFM — чтением документации, книг, etc.

Comment: @falstaf Существовали бы. И были бы при этом гораздо полезнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант, я могу предложить добавить оператор throws в ваш метод
как пример:

public void unparce() throws JSONException

при этом try/catch можно удалить

Answer (score 0):

Потому что JSONException проверяемый, а значит вы либо обязаны его обработать, либо объявить свой метод, как выбрасывающий такой тип исключений.

PS: Книжку что ли по Java прочитайте, прежде чем что-то делать.

Answer (score -1):

Код ужасно большой? А вы хотите по нему брошюру написать, а Издательский дом не пропускает из-за габаритов кода?

До сего дня мне казалось что лучше исключений(тот самый try/catch) не придумали ни в одном языке, но вы меня переубедили!

Что же касается непосредственно вопроса, то это необходимо для исключения ситуаций когда формат JSON ошибочен и это предусмотрено библиотекой парсинга! Если же Вас это не устраивает, то у Вас два выхода: либо писать собственный парсер, либо вносить изменил в используемую библиотеку, но я бы на Вашем месте был бы рад такой заботе, иначе пользователь Вашего приложения может насылать на Вас порчу при постоянных крешах!

Comment: На самом деле, вы не совсем правы. Поскольку неоправданное фанатичное применение `checked exceptions` взамен `unchecked`, действительно создаёт массу неудобств и чрезмерно раздувает код. Типичный пример такого, грхм, не слишком умного и дальновидного подхода — `UnsupportedEncodingException`. Уверен, у многих вызывает раздражение и непонимание, почему его кто-то когда-то решил объявить как `checked`.